# Unable to detect relyably locking of screen within gnome session

Tags: screensaver, gnome-screensaver

I have to detect if the screen is locked or not. It works pretty OK most of the time. BUT: Selecting "Lock screen" (German: "Sperren") on the top right menu and moving the mouse directly afterwards leads to

- a locked screen
- the screen not being turned off
- the session not being detected as "locked"

  - `gnome-screensaver-command --query`
  - `dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver --print-reply=literal /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.GetActive`
  - `loginctl show-session 2` (2 determined via `loginctl list-sessions`)

Any idea on how to detect screen locking in this scenario? I'm using ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04

### Lock screen without mouse movement

Screen is turned off

```
2022-07-09_14:13:02 'gnome-screensaver.sh:boolean false' 'loginctl:Active=yes State=active IdleHint=no IdleSinceHint=1657368161096140 IdleSinceHintMonotonic=104647751555 LockedHint=no' 'xset:Monitor is On' 'gnome-screensaver-command:The screensaver is inactive' -
2022-07-09_14:13:12 'gnome-screensaver.sh:boolean true' 'loginctl:Active=yes State=active IdleHint=yes IdleSinceHint=1657368789735058 IdleSinceHintMonotonic=105276390473 LockedHint=yes' 'xset:Monitor is Off' 'gnome-screensaver-command:The screensaver is active' 628638918
2022-07-09_14:13:22 'gnome-screensaver.sh:boolean true' 'loginctl:Active=yes State=active IdleHint=no IdleSinceHint=1657368801998928 IdleSinceHintMonotonic=105288654344 LockedHint=yes' 'xset:Monitor is On' 'gnome-screensaver-command:The screensaver is active' 12263871
2022-07-09_14:13:32 'gnome-screensaver.sh:boolean false' 'loginctl:Active=yes State=active IdleHint=no IdleSinceHint=1657368801998928 IdleSinceHintMonotonic=105288654344 LockedHint=no' 'xset:Monitor is On' 'gnome-screensaver-command:The screensaver is inactive' -
```

### Lock screen with mouse movement

Screen is **not** turned off

```
2022-07-09_14:14:18 'gnome-screensaver.sh:boolean false' 'loginctl:Active=yes State=active IdleHint=no IdleSinceHint=1657368801998928 IdleSinceHintMonotonic=105288654344 LockedHint=no' 'xset:Monitor is On' 'gnome-screensaver-command:The screensaver is inactive' -
2022-07-09_14:14:28 'gnome-screensaver.sh:boolean false' 'loginctl:Active=yes State=active IdleHint=no IdleSinceHint=1657368801998928 IdleSinceHintMonotonic=105288654344 LockedHint=no' 'xset:Monitor is On' 'gnome-screensaver-command:The screensaver is inactive' -
2022-07-09_14:14:38 'gnome-screensaver.sh:boolean false' 'loginctl:Active=yes State=active IdleHint=no IdleSinceHint=1657368801998928 IdleSinceHintMonotonic=105288654344 LockedHint=no' 'xset:Monitor is On' 'gnome-screensaver-command:The screensaver is inactive' -
2022-07-09_14:14:48 'gnome-screensaver.sh:boolean false' 'loginctl:Active=yes State=active IdleHint=no IdleSinceHint=1657368801998928 IdleSinceHintMonotonic=105288654344 LockedHint=no' 'xset:Monitor is On' 'gnome-screensaver-command:The screensaver is inactive' -
```

Comment: This may have not worked for you, but the loginctl output was good enough for my purposes. Thanks for writing such a detailed and helpful question!